# Sorting an rdd after using groupbykey using values

Tags: java, apache-spark, group-by, rdd

I have `JavaPairRDD` as

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Row>> rdd = mydataset.orderBy("orderfield1", "orderfield2").javaRDD().mapToPair(row -> new Tuple2<>(row.getAs("id").toString(), row)).groupByKey()
```

As `groupbykey()` doesn't maintain order `orderby` doesn't work here.
I want to order the `Iterable<Row>` using some of the fields from dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform the `Iterable` into a `List` and then sort that list like below. I assume that your sorting field is called `x` and that it is of type String but you can obviously adapt that to your specific case.

```java
String sortingField = "x"
JavaPairRDD<String, List<Row>> rdd = mydataset
    .javaRDD()
    .mapToPair(row -> new Tuple2<>(row.getAs("id").toString(), row))
    .groupByKey()
    .mapValues(it -> {
        List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        it.forEach(rows::add);
        rows.sort(
            (Row a, Row b) -> a.<String>getAs(sortingField).compareTo(b.<String>getAs(sortingField))
        );
        return rows;
    });
```

Note that this is much simpler to write in scala:

```scala
val rdd = mydataset
    .rdd
    .map(row => (row.getAs("id").toString, row))
    .groupByKey
    .mapValues( _.toSeq.sortBy(_.getAs[String]("x")))
```